# Proving a relation on the Euclidean volume

Tags: differential-geometry

I have seen the following equalities in some paper
$$Vol(B^n (1)) = \frac 1 n .Vol(S^{n-1}) = \frac 1 n .Vol(S^{n-2}) .\int_0 ^{\pi} \sin^{n-2}(t) dt.$$
Here $B^n (1)$ and $S^n $  denote the unit ball and the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ respectively  and "Vol" denote  the Euclidean volume.

I would like to prove them, but i do not know how one can do it.

Could somebody please help me to understand this?

Comment: Use spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equality can be proved using the divergence theorem: the vector field $ x $ has $ \operatorname{div}{x} = n$, so the divergence theorem gives
$$ \operatorname{Vol}{(S^{n-1})} = \int_{S^{n-1}} x \cdot dS = \int_{B^n(1)} \operatorname{div}{x} \, dV = n \operatorname{Vol}{(B^n(1))}. $$

The second needs hyperspherical coordinates: we can parametrise the sphere by
$$ x_1 = \cos{\theta_1} \\
x_2 = \sin{\theta_1}\cos{\theta_2} \\
\vdots \\
x_n = \sin{\theta_1} \sin{\theta_2} \dotsm \sin{\theta_{n-1}}, $$
where all but $\theta_{n-1}$ range between $0$ and $\pi$, the last between $0$ and $2\pi$.
We find that the surface element associated to this is
$$ \sin^{n-2}{\theta_1} \sin^{n-3}{\theta_2} \dotsm \sin{\theta_{n-2}} \, d\theta_1 \dotsm d\theta_{n-1}. $$
Integrating over the whole surface and separating the $\theta_1$ integral, we find
$$ \operatorname{Vol}{(S^{n-1})} = \int \dotsi \int \sin^{n-2}{\theta_1} \sin^{n-3}{\theta_2} \dotsm \sin{\theta_{n-2}} \, d\theta_1 \dotsm d\theta_{n-1} \\
= \left( \int_0^{\pi} \sin^{n-2}{\theta_1} \, d\theta_1 \right) \left( \int \dotsi \int \sin^{n-3}{\theta_2} \dotsm \sin{\theta_{n-2}} \, d\theta_2 \dotsm d\theta_{n-1} \right). $$
But the remaining multiple integral is just the volume of $S^{n-2}$ if we relabel the variables.